# Shape of logits and labels mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xx/abc/Final.py", line 167, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\xx\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:/Users/xx/abc/Final.py", line 148, in main
    hooks=[logging_hook])
  File "C:\Users\xx\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 363, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\xx\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 843, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\xx\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 856, in _train_model_default
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\xx\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 831, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/xx/abc/Final.py", line 61, in cnn_model_fn
    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
  File "C:\Users\xx\tensorflow\python\ops\losses\losses_impl.py", line 853, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy
    name="xentropy")
  File "C:\Users\xx\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 2046, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
    logits.get_shape()))


ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (100,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (300, 10)).
```

Train input function:

```
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_data},
      y=train_labels,
      batch_size=100,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)
```

**ALL DATASET SHAPES**

```
  print(train_data.shape)
  //Output: (9490, 2352) 

  train_labels = np.asarray(label_MAX[0], dtype=np.int32)


  print(train_labels.shape)
  //Output: (9490,)
  eval_data = datasets[1]  # Returns np.array


  print(eval_data.shape)
  //Output: (3175, 2352)
  eval_labels = np.asarray(label_MAX[1], dtype=np.int32)


  print(eval_labels.shape)
  //Output: (3175,)
```

I read other StackOverflow questions and most of them pointed to the calculation of the loss function as the point of error. The fact that the code sends a batch of 100 labels is causing an issue?

How can I resolve this? Is the fact that the number of images and labels not being a multiple of 100 the root of this issue?

My model is being trained for only 0 and 1
So I suppose I must make a change to this

```
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)
```

and change number of units to 2?

Comment: Can you show how you build your model ?

Comment: @Sunreef this is the tutorial I am following 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers

Comment: Looks like you should give batches of 300 for the labels since your logits have size (300, 10).

Comment: @Sunreef I changed the value of the batch_size parameter of the train input function to 300 and I got this error: 
The shape of labels (received (300,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (900, 2)) What should I do?

Also I changed the number of units in the logits layer to 2 since I'm training only for 0 and 1. This would be an apt approach right?

Comment: @Sunreef This is the link to the gist 
https://gist.github.com/abhay-iy97/94011a3bc0e3a0ae3b0048199f658089

My basic idea is to input my own image and label data instead of the mnist"

Can you please check my image data processing part of the code in the main fn. I'm using 28*28*3 images

Comment: I had a similar issue. Your problem is most likely due to using different feature sizes than the tutorial. For me, I had to change this line: ```pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])``` to ```pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, image_width_in_pixels / 4 * image_height_in_pixels / 4 * 64])``` I had to do some additional resizing on some of the other lines as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes form the fact that you are using RGB images. The model is designed to be used with grayscale images as shown in the line `input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])` near the top of the CNN definition. Having 3 channels instead of 1 means that the batch size here will be three times too large.

To fix that, change that line to `input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 3])`.

Comment: I'm having the same error 
```ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (20,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (80, 4)).```
My input layer is already ```tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 3])``` What else could be wrong? 
This is my model : https://gist.github.com/jenyckee/c8090ad2d7639bd54f8ca4238aeb5985

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. I realized that I didn't Flatten my Image data. Once I included the Flatten() layer I am able to process the neural network properly. Could you try adding a Flatten Layer before the Dense Layers?